# Tawbah with a Sufi

Tags: sin, shirk, tawba, sufism

Before joining a Tarikat, I did tauwbah with a Sufi man (I decided not to join a Sufi tarikat).

I am confused if this is a sin or shirk since I’m not sure if this belongs in Sunnah?

Answer (score 2):

Tasawwuf is a heart related knowledge. This is very important knowledge and way. Pure sufism is not sin and shirk. You should identify who is that sufi. Avoiding to follow incorrect way, you should start tasawwuf with  ilm(knowledge).

Answer (score 0):

Sufism is an Islamic practise. It is a practise that has not been established by the Prophet (p.b.u.h). Some people consider it therefore bidah (haram).

The Sufi themselves consider Tasawwuf a inner part of Islam, founded on Sunnah, e.g. [here](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2018), as exercises forming the character.

Many Sunni scholars accept or support sufi practises (mustahabb) if it is well-done.

In any sense, Sufism is not shirk, as Sufi do all in true belief and worship only Allah.

Comment: Tasawwuf as a concept is orthodox. However the tenants themselves are a different matter. We need to be careful with certain heretical and blasphemous beliefs and practices that have crept into this pure science.

Comment: @Afiq Agree. It depends even more than in general on the teacher, and not all teachers are good. And also a bad general Islam teacher can do damage.